# Syntax error in inline functions in C language

Tags: c

I am trying below simple example by using inline functions in C language. Its giving me a compilation error(on inline function) as shown below.

```
  Error test.c 1: Declaration Syntax Error
```

My C code is as shown below

```
inline int square(int a)
{
    return(a*a);
}
void main()
{
    int no,result;
    clrscr();
    printf("\nEnter the number ");
    scanf("%d",&no);
    result=square(no);
    printf("\n Square is %d ",result);
    getch();

 }
```

Comment: `printf("\n Square is %d ",result)` -> `printf("\n Square is %d ",result);` That is, missing semi-colon. If that is not the problem then please give the full error msg including line number.

Comment: It was typo while posting the question. I am getting error message on inline function definition line. Line no 1.

Comment: void main ?? it should be `int main(void)` or `int main()`

Comment: You mean like `static inline int square(int a)`? And `void main()` is only valid in a *freestanding environment* (without an OS) where the name of the startup function is *implementation defined*, otherwise, see: [C11 Standard - §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup(p1)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p1). See also: [What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/)

Comment: What compiler are you using and what command-line options are you using?

Comment: Adam : I am not returning anything from main. That's why, I used return type as void for main function. Thanks.

Comment: Dai - I am using Turbo C++ 3.2.

Comment: The one with the last release in 1996?

Comment: @Vicky Borland TurboC++ 3x is from the early 1990s. The `inline` keyword wasn't added to C until C99. TurboC++ never supported C99.

Comment: oh ok, thanks David and Dai. Not sure why but I am seeing release date of Turbo C++ 3.2 in 2017 on google. May be some changes...

Comment: @Vicky What do you see when you go "Help > About"? Please post a screenshot in an update to your question - I'm very curious!

Comment: Dai ---- its showing version 3.0 and year 1990

Comment: @Vicky **Wow!** - wait a minute, how are you even running it? In 1990 there was only Win16, not Win32, and you can't run most Win16 programs on Windows 10. I'd love to see a screenshot of this.

Comment: Dai - I have windows 7 not 10. I can send the screenshots. But, I am not aware of the option how to  post image here.

Comment: @All - let me try this example on latest version. Will get back to you in case of any issues. Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am using Turbo C++ 3.2

There's your problem:

- [Borland TurboC++ 3.2 dates from around 1992-1996](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borland_C%2B%2B), apparently.

  - It hasn't been updated since version 5.02 (released in 1997).
- [The `inline` keyword was added to C in C99](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/inline).
- [C99 came out in 1999](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99), which more astute readers may recognize as a year that happened no less than two years after 1997... and your version of TurboC++ 3.2, which as previously discussed, predates not only 1997, but also 1999 as well.

Solution:

- Use a C compiler released in the past 20 years that supports C99.

  - C++ compilers are not C compilers, btw.

    - While C++ inherits most of C, which means most C++ compilers support a good subset of C, they do not need to support all of C99, C11, C18, C2x, etc.